# Offline webapp on iPad

Tags: ipad, web-applications, offline

I have a website written in php / javascript. It's quite simple, basically :

- on the first page it shows a list of category
- when a category is clicked, a new page is displayed with a list of pictures (that can be clicked to get a bigger version, using AJAX) and some text details

I'd like to be able to browse this site offline on an iPad, what would be the better way ?
I saw it is possible to add some html5 caching capability, would this be the way to go ?

Answer (score 2):

You should try the HTML5's caching and/or persistent storage feature. You can save app data or even whole files, and either access them from JavaScript to display, or ask the browser to seamlessly display the cached files when there's no Internet connection. Some links may help:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/ <- this one is the caching-related
http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/ <- and this is about persistent storage.

Hope that helps, Árpád

Comment: thanks, I'll check this. Thinking about it, my concern is also regarding AJAX calls that may be harder to handle.